# binding the table and chart on dropdown select

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I do have 5 tables and 2 charts and one drop down menu.i have to bind all these tables and charts on drop down select.i am using ajax for this..
for drop down i have written the code as

```
<select id="userclicked"> <?php foreach($model["combouser"] as &$obj){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $obj["id"];?>" id="<?php echo $obj["id"];?>" data-id="<?php echo $obj["id"];?>"><?php echo $obj["name"]; ?></option>
            <?php }?>
    </select>
```

and ajax for this which i will be using is as follows:

```
$("#userclicked").live('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: root + "home/index/" + $(this).attr("value") + "?json",
            success: function (data) {
                ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(data.list), document.getElementById("listform"));
                ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(data.activetime), document.getElementById("listform"));

            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        return false;
    });

    refreshMyModel(model);
});
```

please suggest me on this...

Comment: root is defined? What is not working?

Comment: binding is not being taking palce..when i click any one from the drop down list five query are getting fired which are used to show the data in the table and in  the form of chart.bt no binding is taking place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 'change' on event on a select tag. Like so:

```
$("#userclicked").live('change', function () {
```

However be aware that the .live() function is deprecated and you should now use .on()